# Tags (keywords) are missing from the Youtube API video feed when using category search

Tags: youtube-api

When I make an authorized call for Youtube videos, I get all the tags/keywords in the feed.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2

However, if I want to filter this result by a single keyword/category, the tags are not returned by the API. Example, I want to reduce the number of videos in the feed by tag "English"/"French".

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/-/English?alt=jsonc&v=2

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behavior; [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html) explains how your second request is going against the search index, which will never return keywords/tags in the response.